# start button in jmeter does not work

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I was trying to run a very simple load test scenario, but when i click on the start button in jmeter it starts and immediately stop for reasons i dont understand.

Its a  very simple test plan with a thread group, http request default and two listeners.

For testing purpose i set the users to one and the URL in the request defaults as " jmeter.apache.org"

i clicked on the start button, but it immediately stops. i enabled the log viewer and this was the log

```
2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []  2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*)  2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : user
_group  
2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 2 threads for group user
_group.  
2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error  
2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 2 ramp-up 1 perThread 500.0 delayedStart=false  
2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1  2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started  
2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: user _group 1-1  2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: user _group 1-1  2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: user _group 1-2  2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: user _group 1-2  2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test  
2014/06/13 14:08:17 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local***
```

Hope someone can help to understand what the situation is.

Answer (score 0):

From the log it looks like that both threads have finished. Try adding a listener like [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) (don't forget to disable/remove it for real load testing) to see requests/responses details.

Another option is to run JMeter [in non-GUI command line mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) as follows:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/script.jmx -l /path/to/results.csv
```

And after test finishes open results.csv in Excel or equivalent.

The second option is designed for real load testing as JMeter in GUI mode will destroy your load test for number of threads > 50.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your Thread Group the "Loop count" parameter is 0.
Try with number >=1 .

Comment: thanks for the comment man, i could solve the issue. it was something with the SSL certificate which threw an error and exited the playback.